# Repeating row for every report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a table report.

I have put `no`, `agency name`, `year 1`, `year 2`, `year 3`, `year 4`, `year 5` and the total for the first row and the second row. I've put all sum of `year 1`, `year 2`, `year 3`, `year 4`, `year 5` and total of agencies in the `Detail` band. After that, I put the line chart layout. In the end, I put the **`page break`** with *`$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5==0`* condition. But the problem is repetitive data along both the row. How to solve this problem? I want to view 5 row per page for an one report. The result are still the same.

Here i attach my code:

> **Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="charttest" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="99"/>
    <parameter name="P_YEAR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Documents and Settings\\NT\\Desktop\\CHART\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>

    <field name="PARENT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PARENT_NAME_SECTOR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_PARENT_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_CODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AGENCY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="YEAR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SECTOR_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SECTOR_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DYEAR1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR2" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR3" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR4" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="DYEAR5" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="YR1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR2" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR3" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR4" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="YR5" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="YR1_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR2_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR3_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR3}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR4_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR4}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR5_1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR1_2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR2_2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR2}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR3_2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR3}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR4_2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR4}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="YR5_2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="sumA" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}+$F{YR2}+$F{YR3}+$F{YR4}+$F{YR5}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Agency">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{PARENT_NAME_SECTOR}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="192">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="622" y="83" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SECTOR_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="64" y="145" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AGENCY_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="74" y="83" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="18" y="83" width="56" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Year From :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="18" y="104" width="56" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Year To :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="574" y="83" width="48" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Sector :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="18" y="145" width="46" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Agency :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="74" y="104" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="802" height="26"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[5 YEAR STATISTICS ON APPLICATION RECEIVED (BY ALL AGENCIES)]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="18" y="165" width="33" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[No.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="425" y="178" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="510" y="178" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="595" y="178" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR5}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="340" y="178" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="255" y="178" width="85" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DYEAR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="255" y="165" width="425" height="13"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Year]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="51" y="165" width="204" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Agency Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="680" y="165" width="85" height="27"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="395">
                <lineChart>
                    <chart>
                        <reportElement x="30" y="42" width="772" height="353"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Group" resetGroup="Agency" incrementType="Report"/>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{PARENT_NAME_SECTOR}]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{YEAR}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <linePlot>
                        <plot/>
                    </linePlot>
                </lineChart>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR2_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="18" y="0" width="237" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[                                                                          Total]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="255" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR1_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="425" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR3_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="510" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR4_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="595" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{YR5_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="680" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($V{YR1_1}.intValue() + $V{YR2_1}.intValue()+
$V{YR3_1}.intValue()+ $V{YR4_1}.intValue())+ $V{YR5_1}.intValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="510" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="51" y="0" width="204" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PARENT_NAME_SECTOR}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="18" y="0" width="33" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="255" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="425" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="595" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YR5}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="680" y="0" width="85" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new Integer($F{YR1}.intValue() + $F{YR2}.intValue()+ $F{YR3}.intValue()+ $F{YR4}.intValue())+ $F{YR5}.intValue()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="19" width="802" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5 == 0)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post the screenshoot of your report's design (in iReport) and the jrxml file?

Comment: And what about the screenshot of the `Designer` view?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: the result that im expecting is i want 5 row data perpage and total with line chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have 5 detail rows followed by the graph, and then a linebreak? The reason this is not happening is because you have the linegraph printing after every detail row. So it never actually hits the 5th row. You need to move the line graph to the `agnesi Group Footer 1` section.

**UPDATE:** If you only want the column header on the first page, then you need to add a printWhenExpression to it that has `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1`

**2nd UPDATE:** You have a few things wrong with your report.

- One you put a page break in your Page Footer. That should not be
  there. It makes does not make since to put a page break in the footer
  at all.
- Two You have multiple detail sections. I do not think that is going
  to work the way you expect it to. The items in your Detail 2 section
  more than likely be in the `Agency Group Footer 1` with **NO Page
  Break**.
- Three your column header does not seem right. You are referencing
  Fields in there. Fields is the data in your datasource that are
  iterated over in the group and detail section. As a best Guess this
  should be moved into the `Agency Group Header 1` instead of the
  column header.
- Lastly the only place you should put a page break in your case is in
  the `Detail 1` section with the print when expression
  `($V{REPORT_COUNT} % 5) == 0`

Something I find that helps me keep things clearer is to delete the sections altogether that I am not using. Once you do the things above I told you about, you could for example delete the title, page header, column header, page footer, and summary sections.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I've tried and it succeeded. But the problem now is it can't read data for the last page when the data is less than 5. I think the problem are "$ V {REPORT_COUNT}% 5 == 0". Here i have attach the pictures. In the pictures, I have put the condition "$ V {REPORT_COUNT}% 5 == 0" in the "print When expression" in "Detail2" and "Group footer"

Comment: Can you show and tell me or step by step how to arrange the report properly.My problem now is when report less than 5 row.it can't show the total and line chart. i have try many times but it still can't work.:(

Comment: No I can not. Sorry, you have not even posted your the contents of jrxml file, so all anybody has to look at is links to screenshots linked all over the place. Sorry man. Take some time, clean up and organize your question above, and put the text of your jrxml (not a screenshot) in the question. Maybe then someone can help you help yourself. Until you show more effort, you are probably on your own.

Comment: my point is do you have any suggestion how display the data when data for the last page less than 5. if you see back the pictures you will see data for the last page not appear.The data only can view 5 row and other than that,it will not show.i have try send my jrxml file but it cannot. can you show me how to put the code. i have try many times but it still can't work

Comment: Up at the top right below your question you will have a link to labeled edit in light grey. After clicking it you will get a box with the question in it that you can change what you have written, add text, remove text, add images, etc. If you are using iReport, open your jrxml file there, and go to the xml tab. Copy all that text into your question. Highlight the xml you just pasted and click the button labeled {} to format it as code. That is the basics of it, it does not have to look perfect, just need the text there. Others can clean it up if need be.

Comment: Can you give me shot screen example for this chart.i have try many times but it does'nt work.:(